# Issue with metasploit RHOST LHOST

Tags: metasploit

I'm having a weird bug. I've tried this result on two different VM's on the latest Metasploit version.

```
msf exploit(windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi) > show options

Module options (exploit/windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi):

   Name     Current Setting  Required  Description
   ----     ---------------  --------  -----------
   RHOST                     yes       The target address
   RPORT    445              yes       The SMB service port (TCP)
   SMBPIPE  BROWSER          yes       The pipe name to use (BROWSER, SRVSVC)


Payload options (windows/meterpreter/bind_tcp):

   Name      Current Setting  Required  Description
   ----      ---------------  --------  -----------
   EXITFUNC  thread           yes       Exit technique (Accepted: '', seh, thread, process, none)
   LPORT     4444             yes       The listen port
   RHOST                      no        The target address
```

For some reason, the payload only gives me the RHOST option so I cannot set the LHOST. I've tried setting it anyway but I cannot set it.

Comment: Please read the documentation.

Comment: Why do you want to set LHOST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `bind_tcp` payload doesn't require a `LHOST` because it doesn't initially make an outgoing connection. Instead, it listens (binds) to the specified port.

Perhaps you are wanting to use a `reverse_tcp` payload, this would require a `LHOST` and `LPORT` to be specified to connect to.